# Where do I find the fusible link in my 2001 Mitsubishi Eclipse V6?

Tags: electrical, headlight, wiring, mitsubishi, fuse

The right headlight low beam circuit fails to provide power to the headlight; there was an intermittent short at the headlight connector between the ground and power leads.

The relay is operational so I believe the fusible link has blown and needs replacement.

My question is *where* specifically in the wiring is the fusible link located? Is it near the headlight connector connection or closer to the relay/fuse box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low beam circuit uses dedicated fuses. There are no fusible links in the headlamp circuits. In your case fuse 11 is the passenger side low beam.

[image]
[image]

Comment: According to an imprinted diagram on the inside of the fuse case cover, it's fuse 9 rather than 11. 3.0 V6 vs. 4 cyl? So I just tested *all* 10 Amp fuses in that box with a meter and they are *all* intact. Is there any way a wire would fail before the fuse would? I suppose continuity test next from fuse to headlight connector. If it's open is it general practice to just bypass, run a new, separate wire?

Comment: @docscience sure wires can fail before fuses. Rodents, rubbing etc... it would be uncommon for the wire to burn itself out before the fuse blows though. if your continuity test fails and you can’t find where the wire is broken, it’s totally fine to run a new wire from the fuse to the headlight.